# cant set alias, zsh: command not found

Tags: zsh

I have `~/.bash_aliases` file as follows:

```
function gittag() {
         CMD="git tag -a ${1} -m '${1}'"
         echo $CMD
         `$CMD`
}
```

I reference this file in my `.zshrc`:

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

However the alias does not work:

```
➜  ~ gittag foo      
git tag -a foo -m 'foo'
gittag:3: command not found: git tag -a foo -m 'foo'
➜  ~
```

Comment: The alias is found 
perhaps the $PATH is not being passed to into the function? Also you might want to change the backticks to the $(COMMAND) format

Comment: See [Bash FAQ 050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't stuff a command in a variable just because you think it will make it easier to update the command and the logging in sync. It creates a bigger problem, namely that you are relying on word-splitting to not break the command. (And you *do* need word-splitting to some extent, to break `$CMD` up in to `git` and its arguments.)

Just use the following function.

```
gittag() {
    echo "git tag -a '$1' -m '$1'"
    git tag -a "$1" -m "$1"
}
```